# Yii2 composer update after cloning from bitbucket

Tags: yii2, composer-php, bower, yii2-advanced-app

So I cloned my Yii2-advanced project from bitbucket. It is without the vendor folder so I have to run `composer update` to install all plugins. But when I do this I get an errors :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - jlorente/yii2-widget-remainingcharacters dev-master requires bower-asset/jquery-remaining-characters ~1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - jlorente/yii2-widget-remainingcharacters 1.0.1 requires bower-asset/jquery-remaining-characters ~1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - jlorente/yii2-widget-remainingcharacters 1.0.0 requires bower-asset/jquery-remaining-characters ~1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for jlorente/yii2-widget-remainingcharacters * -> satisfiable by jlorente/yii2-widget-remainingcharacters[1.0.0, 1.0.1, dev-master].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

So my requirements are not ok. Good. I installed `jquery-remaining-characters ~1.0.0` but error is still the same. This kind of problem happens few times already and I want to learn how to handle it. Also there is no typo in the package name and I tried with both `stable` and `dev` minimum-stability options. What should be done and what is exactly the problem with the composer/bower packeges in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use [asset-packagist](https://asset-packagist.org/) - add its repository to your `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
]
```

Or install [`fxp/composer-asset-plugin`](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin) globally:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.4"
```